# Is it possible to get on localhost from mobile when your computer is on ethernet connection?

Tags: localhost, server

Pretty much the title.

If I'm hosting a server on my PC (which is connected via ethernet to my router) for Jekyll or whatever, is it possible for my mobile to connect to the localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, 
if you know your ip address, just hit the browser enter http://**your_ip_goes_here**:**your_port**

if you are windows, you can know your ip via cmd **ipconfig**
 & in linux **ip addr show**

Answer (score 0):

**Connect internally:**
   You must know your *servers* internal ip address if your phone is connected to
   home network via wifi.

**Connect externally:**
   If you turn off you phone's wifi and use data connection, your phone
   is outside your home network and you can then use your *servers* external ip
   address to connect. Also that you must configure your router to
   forward the service port of the server.

You must realize the above to not trip,stumble, and beat on a door that is not open.